# Loading dump file in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, dmp

I am unsuccessfully trying to load .DMP file from visual studio it is giving me headache now...any help will be highly appreciated.

The windows form C# application is in VS 2005 framework 2.0 running on a windows 7 machine

I run the .exe from the debug folder (i-e the exe was generated by building the solution in "Debug" mode and "Mixed platform" rather than "Release" mode).

Open task manager, select the process, right click and select "create dump file" which creates myapp.dmp file.

The dmp file was created when the application was running fine and there was no exception. I am only trying to see where were all the threads at the time of user dump creation.

I then copy myapp.dmp file in the same folder where I was ran the application from. That folder has all the dlls and pdb files and .exe.

I double click myapp.dmp, the file shows up in solution explorer but when I double click it in the solution explorer nothing happens. I run using F5 but I get error message saying "Debugging information for myapp.exe" cant be found or does not match. No native symbols in symbol file.

I also try to open the .dmp file from Visual Studio.Net "File Menu" + "Open" and select the .dmp file. A big Binary file opens up in the visual studio.

Comment: Check this out to know more about loading dmp files into visual studio and setting symbols paths http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk551230.aspx

Comment: Yes, I also added path name to the symbol location list but still getting the same error. Are there any settings/scenarios under which .dmp file does NOT work with visual studio? I tried loading the symbol file manually but for that I am unable to locate the "Modules" window. I also reset my environment settings to both Visual C# and C++ but still cant locate it.

Comment: ok, the modules window can only be opened during the debugging. So since I cant debug the dmp file yet, I can not load symbol path manually either.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the symbol path in visual studio: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy%28v=vs.80%29.aspx, it should be able to find the symbols for your app so long as the pdbs are located either in the same folder as where the app was run and the private symbols were not stripped, or you add the path to these pdbs as per the link. You also need the path to the MS symbols as per the link.